# Wpf rotating window?

Tags: wpf, animation, storyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to rotate a WPF Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710320/how-to-rotate-a-wpf-window)

Is it possible to add LayoutTransform or RenderTransform to the whole window in WPF ?

I want to make it rotating when its being loaded.

I can not find anything on the internet about this issue.

Currently I am applying a rotating animation to the utmost grid in the window, but it is 
better to have the whole window rotating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried applying the transform to the window? What was the result?

Comment: @jjrdk : Of course I have applied but it just work in design mode(MS Blend).

Comment: @Klaus78 thanks for the link. So we can conclude that we have to build window structure and behavior from the scratch! I thought about that solution but I told to myself that it is not an elegant way. But now it seems that it is the only way. Anyway thanks Klaus. If you add it as an answer I will accept it.