# Button inside a custom skewed window doesn't allways get mouseEnter event

Tags: wpf, transform

Here is my code:

```
 <Window x:Class="WPFStackOverFlow.SkewWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="687">

<Border BorderBrush="Green" BorderThickness="2" Background="White" Width="360" Height="360">
    <Border.RenderTransform>  
        <SkewTransform AngleX="-23" AngleY="10"></SkewTransform>
    </Border.RenderTransform>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="23" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="X" Width="23" Name="button1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="button1_Click" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Height="100" Width="200"></Button>
            <TextBlock Text="Some very very long Text" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

When I move the mouse cursor over the button sometimes it get focus and sometimes it doesn't. How can I make the button inside this custom window to be like a button in a regular window?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rotate a WPF Window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710320/how-to-rotate-a-wpf-window)

Comment: Exception is thrown: _"Transform is not valid for Window."_

Comment: No, exception is not thrown whan I run my code. Just nothing happens - the window opens normally.

Comment: Exception "Transform is not valid for Window." IS thrown, but it is being swallowed and will not crash your application. If you check the output window you will see 'A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll'. You can also catch the exception if you surround `this.RenderTransform = ST;` by a try/catch block. Anyway, you can't apply transformations to windows, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can apply transformations to windows.

You can apply them to the controls inside windows.

If you need to simulate transformations to windows you can try something similar to what is described in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710320/how-to-rotate-a-wpf-window).